# push 1D array to 2D array in first position with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

i tried to push an array to other array in specific order
with this javascript code :

```
var arr1=["A","B","C","D","E","F"];
var arr2=["1","2","3"]

console.log(arr1.splice(0,-1,arr2));

its reutn [];

my desire rusult : ["1","2","3","A","B","C","D","F"]
```

please any body show me how to achieve my desire result with splice function
ps : i can achieve this with loop

Thx

**EDIT**: sorry, My question was misleading. This is my actual condition:

```
arr1 :[["A","B","C"],["D","E","F"]]
arr2 :["1","2","3"]
```

Expected output : `[["1,"2","3","A","B","C"],["1","2","3","D","E","F"]]`

I have tried:

```
arr1.map(function(e) {
    return e.splice(0, -1, arra2)
});
```

but I got: `[],[]`

Comment: do you want a new variable or an update?

Comment: Where is `E` gone from the output? :p

Comment: Even with your edit Rio it's still a duplicate, the question is the same just using `map` as well

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like this `const result = [...arr2, ...arr1];`

Code:

```js
const arr1 = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"];
const arr2 = ["1","2","3"]
const result = [...arr2, ...arr1];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I love this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Since other solutions creates a *new array* as result, we could use an approach by modifying *in-place* your original array by using `unshift` method in combination with *spread syntax*.

```js
var arr1=["A","B","C","D","E","F"];
var arr2=["1","2","3"]

arr1.unshift(...arr2);
console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use `splice`? The `concat` methods does exactly what you want to achieve.

```js
var arr1=["A","B","C","D","E","F"];
var arr2=["1","2","3"]

var result = arr2.concat(arr1);
console.log(result);

// If you're okay with using spread syntax (doesn't work in IE), you could just:
console.log([...arr2, ...arr1]);
```

Comment: uisng concate, can be done if arra1 and array2 in same dimension, but in my case arr1 is 2D and arr1 1D, so i can't  change the order

Comment: @RioArfani Can you update your example so that arr1 is 2D as you want it to be?

Answer (score 0):

Spliche works for the given array and if you like to add the values of `arr2` at the beginning of the array, then you could splice the array with a spreaded array.

[`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns the array which ts taken out of the given array by the count of the second parameter, which id zero here, and not `-1` whcih makes no sense.

```js
var arr1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
    arr2 = ["1", "2", "3"]

arr1.splice(0, 0, ...arr2); // returns []

console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), return value of `Array.splice` is

> An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is
>   removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are
>   removed, an empty array is returned.

It will not return the updated array and as you are not removing any element, it will return an empty array.

To `add` some entries using `splice` at a particular index, you can try following.

```js
var arr1=["A","B","C","D","E","F"];
var arr2=["1","2","3"]
arr1.splice(0,0, ...arr2);
console.log(arr1);
```